# Lemma 7.3.6 of Liu's Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a problem with a step in the proof of Lemma 7.3.6 of Liu's algebraic geometry. The lemma goes:

> Let $X$ be a Noetherian scheme of dimension $1$. Let $D$ be a Cartier divisor on $X$. Then there exists two non-zero effective Cartier divisors $E$ and $F$ on $X$ such that $D = E-F$.

Proof: Suppose $D$ is represented by $\{(U_i,f_i)\}_i$ with $U_i = \mathrm{Spec}\,A_i$ affine open and $f_i = a_i/b_i$ with $a_i \in A_i$ and $b_i$ is non-zero divisor in $A_i$. Then $V(b_i) \subset U_i$ is a finite set. As $b_i$ is non-zero divisor, $V(b_i)$ does not contain minimal prime ideals of $A_i$. Hence, $V(b_i)$ is closed in $X$.

**I don't know why $V(b_i)$ is also closed in $X$**

Please help me on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the concept of specialization/generalization: if $x\in \overline{\{x'\}}$, we say that $x$ is a specialization of $x'$ (or $x'$ is a generalization of $x$). The Krull dimension of a sober topological space may be computed as the length of the longest chain of nontrivial specializations: chains of proper inclusions of closed irreducible subsets exactly correspond to chains of specializations by considering their generic points.

Now to our specific scenario. Since $V(b_i)$ is a finite set, it suffices to show that each point is closed in order to show that $V(b_i)$ is closed. Since schemes are sober and $X$ is of dimension $1$, this means that any chain of specializations can only have one nontrivial inclusion. By assumption, any point $p\in V(b_i)$ has a nontrivial generalization corresponding to some minimal prime of $U_i$. If $p$ had a nontrivial specialization, then we would have a chain of two nontrivial specializations, contradicting the assumption $X$ was of dimension one. So $\overline{\{p\}}=\{p\}$, or $p$ is a closed point.

The moral of the story here is that schemes of dimension one only have two types of points: closed points and generic points of one-dimensional irreducible components. By the assumption that $V(b_i)$ contains no generic points, it must consist entirely of closed points.

Comment: Thanks, that answered my question. But in your last paragraph, aren't closed points of codimension $1$, while generic points of codimension $0$?

Comment: I rephrased that sentence to capture my intention better.